# URL routing во Flask

Tags: python, apache, flask

Начал изучать Flask, читая учебник Dwyer-а, и случился затык когда перешёл к теме о URL роутинге. Вроде как написал код как в учебнике, с минимальными изменениями, но при попытке зайти на страницу выдаёт 404.

Код скрипта на питоне:

```
import feedparser

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

RSS_FEEDS = {
    'cnn': 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss',
    'fox': 'http://feeds.foxnews.com/foxnews/latest',
    'iol': 'http://www.iol.co.za/cmlink/1.640',
}


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/cnn")
def cnn():
    return get_news('cnn')


@app.route("/fox")
def fox():
    return get_news('fox')


def get_news(publication):
    feed = feedparser.parse(RSS_FEEDS[publication])
    first_article = feed['entries'][0]
    return """<html>
        <body>
            <h1>Headlines </h1>
            <b>{0}</b> <br/>
            <i>{1}</i> <br/>
            <p>{2}</p> <br/>
        </body>
    </html>""".format(
        first_article.get("title"),
        first_article.get("published"),
        first_article.get("summary"),
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

При этом когда захожу в корень, то получаю на выходе ту же страницу, которую использовал в предыдущей задаче, но в скрипте о ней уже ни слова, так что подозреваю, что проблема может быть и не в скрипте вовсе.

Comment: Что за предыдущая задача? Что пишет данный скрипт при запуске, пишет ли что он успешно запустился на указанном порту или что порт занят уже вашим предыдущим скриптом? На какую именно страницу вы заходите, когда получаете 404?

Comment: @CrazyElf Предыдущей задачей было вывести RSS одного из сайтов на заглавную страницу. Это у меня получилось сделать. При запуске вручную скрипт пишет, что он успешно запущен. По идее его не нужно запускать вручную, это делается за счёт wsgi модуля. 404-ю ошибку я получаю, когда захожу на /cnn или /fox. Apache в логах пишет: "Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/headlines/headlines.wsgi", но этот скрипт там точно есть, а что означает "unable to stat" я попросту не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Дело было в конфигурации сайта для apache-а. Исправил в WSGIScriptAlias первый параметр на корневую папку и всё пошло как по маслу.